# A question on Bertrand's paradox

Tags: pr.probability

Can Bertrand's paradoxical example be "constructed" in a way to get a probability (of chord longer than the side of the inscribed equilateral triangle) equal to 1/n, for any integer n.

For example, if one chooses to model a random chord by choosing two random points on the circle, the probability turns out to be 1/3. If one choose to model a random chord by its mid-point, the probability is 1/4. And, possibly a few other constructs exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The length $L$ of the random chord in the unit disk is determined by the distance $D$ of the midpoint of the random chord from the center of the disk:
$$L=2\sqrt{1-D^2}.$$

So, the condition $P(L>\sqrt3)=1/n$ is equivalent to the condition $P(D<1/2)=1/n$. There are infinitely many probability distributions of $D$ on the interval $[0,1]$ satisfying the latter condition; we can even require that the distribution of the random midpoint be rotationally invariant.

---

In the "standard" settings of [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)#Bertrand%27s_formulation_of_the_problem), $D$ has the densities $f$ given by following formulas:

- $f(d)=\dfrac2{\pi\sqrt{1-d^2}}\,1(0<d<1)$ for the "random endpoints" method;
- $f(d)=1(0<d<1)$ for the "random radial point" method;
- $f(d)=2d\,1(0<d<1)$ for the "random midpoint" method.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @DSM : You are welcome.